# Building multi child tree from list items

Tags: performance, algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

I have a input data structure like this:

```
{
 { {x1,y1,z1,p1}, {x1,y2,z1,p1}, {x1,y3,z1,p1}, {x1,y4,z1,p1} },
 { {x1,y1,z2,p2}, {x1,y2,z2,p2}, {x1,y3,z2,p2}, {x1,y4,z2,p2} },
 { {x1,y1,z3,p3}, {x1,y2,z3,p3}, {x1,y3,z3,p3}, {x1,y4,z3,p3} }
}
```

For complete understanding of the question, each item is a boolean expression (typed ITree), e.g. nn < 42.

What I want to end up with is number of trees showing where each location is:

Top tree:

```
                root
                  |
                 x1
            /     |    \
           z1    z2    z3
            |     |    |
           a(0)  a(4) a(8)
```

Tree a:

```
               root(offset) - offset = o
            /     /     \      \
           y1    y2     y3     y4
           |      |      |      |
         b(o)  b(o+1)  b(o+2) b(o+3)
```

Tree b:

```
               root(offset) - offset = o
            /     |     \
           p1    p2     p3
           |      |      |
           o     o+1    o+2
```

Thus if I have a list that contains values where {x1,y2,z1,p1} would evaluate to true I can trivially see that this is in cell 1 (actually in 0,1), and that a list that contains {x1,y2,z1,p2} it not in any cell.

I have built a functional implementation, however it is quite slow:

```
public MultiIfTreeList Compile(List<List<ITree>> input, out List<MultiIfTreeList> all, out List<int> orderOfLeafs ) {
  //{ { {x,y} }, { {z} } } -> {0:{x.ToString:x, y.ToString:y}, 1:{z.ToString:z}}
  List<Tuple<int, Dictionary<string, ITree>>> andList = ConvertToDictionaryAndFlatten(input);

  orderOfLeafs = new List<int>();
  all = new List<MultiIfTreeList>();
  return BuildIfTree(andList, orderOfLeafs, all);
}

  private MultiIfTreeList BuildIfTree(List<Tuple<int, Dictionary<string, ITree>>> andList, List<int> orderOfLeafs, List<MultiIfTreeList> all)
  {
     if (andList.Count == 0)
        return null;
     var children = new List<MultiIfTree>();

     while (andList.Count > 0)
     {
        //count number of occurances of each statement, ie x1=5 and x2=3 and find the highest one
        Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var exp1 in andList.SelectMany(exp => exp.Item2.Keys))
           if (!counts.ContainsKey(exp1))
              counts[exp1] = 1;
           else
              counts[exp1]++;

        var maxcount = counts.Max(x => x.Value);

        if (maxcount == 1) //OPTIMIZATION: then all are different and we can just do them one at a time
        {
           foreach (var lst in andList)
           {
              var item = lst.Item2.First();
              lst.Item2.Remove(item.Key);
              var idx = orderOfLeafs.Count;
              children.Add(
                 new MultiIfTree
                 {
                    Value = item.Key,
                    Ast = item.Value,
                    LeafsThis = 0,
                    Children = BuildIfTree(new List<Tuple<int, Dictionary<string, ITree>>> { lst }, orderOfLeafs, all),
                    ExpireCountWithChildren = orderOfLeafs.Count - idx,
                 });
           }
           andList.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
           //Make lists of where each statement can be found
           foreach (var kvp in counts.Where(x => x.Value == maxcount))
           {
              var max = kvp.Key;
              var expireindex = expire.Count;
              ITree exp = null;
              var listWithMax = new List<Tuple<int, Dictionary<string, ITree>>>();
              var listWithoutMax = new List<Tuple<int, Dictionary<string, ITree>>>();
              foreach (var lst in andList)
              {
                 var copy = new Dictionary<string, ITree>(lst.Item2);
                 var item = new Tuple<int, Dictionary<string, ITree>>(lst.Item1, copy);
                 if (copy.ContainsKey(max))
                 {
                    exp = copy[max];
                    copy.Remove(max);
                    if (copy.Count == 0)
                       expire.Add(lst.Item1);
                    else
                       listWithMax.Add(item);
                 }
                 else
                    listWithoutMax.Add(item);
              }
              if (exp != null)
                 children.Add(
                    new MultiIfTree
                    {
                       Value = max,
                       Ast = exp,
                       LeafsThis = orderOfLeafs.Count - idx,
                       Children = BuildIfTree(listWithMax, expire, all),
                       LeafCountWithChildren = orderOfLeafs.Count - idx,
                    });
              andList = listWithoutMax;
           }
        }
     }
     var tree = new MultiIfTreeList(children);
     all.Add(tree);
     return tree;
  }
```

On an input that has 25008 lists of 4 expressions each, this takes about 800 msec on my machine.

**Edit 1:**
To actually get top tree, a and b, it is just a simple matter of hashing them, in my particular case of those 25008*4 that ends up as 24000ish trees which is hashed down to 760 unique trees. This part just takes 21msec